# exclude basket cart box from varnish cache

Tags: caching, prestashop, varnish

in prestashop, In above the site there is a box (which seems ajax), show number of product that customer select.
It is called from the following module:
data-refresh-url="//xyz.com/module/ps_shoppingcart/ajax"

When cache a page the number of this box may be displayed incorrectly, (Displays the last number before the page is cached).
I want exclude this segment from varnish cache. How should this be done?

[image]

Comment: Can you show me your vcl config ?

Comment: Yes
https://anotepad.com/notes/mwapycep

Comment: I found this details:
https://postimg.cc/BP0kWhtp

but I cant exclude shopping box ajax view from cache

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following VCL code to exclude `/module/ps_shoppingcart/ajax` from the cache:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if(req.url ~ "^/module/ps_shoppingcart/ajax") {
        return(pass);
    }
}
```

The regular expression pattern will not only exclude requests based on the exact URL, but also when it matches a URL that starts with `/module/ps_shoppingcart/ajax`

**IMPORTANT: take the if-statement from the `vcl_recv` subroutine and add it to the bottom of the `vcl_recv` subroutine right before the `return(hash)` line!**

Comment: Unfortunately, this was not correct and had no effect

Comment: Be sure to empty the cache before you test. If that doesn't work, please provide the output for the following command: `varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl ~ '^/module/ps_shoppingcart/ajax'"`. We can then inspect what's really going on.

Comment: Yes I purge all cache before test, varnishlog command not show anything. 
you can view body structure of this box in this link:
https://ufile.io/rszqmwu1

Comment: Can you check whether or not this AJAX call is called from your browser? Can you also verify that the hostname of this URL actually points to your Varnish server? And if you run `varnishlog -g request` without URL filter do you see anything coming in?

Comment: On non-cached pages this value is displayed in the correct browser. Yes the cache is done .  you can see cache log here:
https://anotepad.com/notes/a2685nwd

Comment: I test this regex but not work :(
  `if (req.method == "GET" && (req.url ~ "/ajax" || req.url ~ "^/ajax")) {
        return (pass);`

Comment: The logs are helpful, but don't include references to `Module/ps_shoppingcart/ajax`. At least we know traffic pass through Varnish. The best way forward is if you could share your entire VCL file. This will allow me to understand what is happening in terms of caching rules.

Comment: My vcl content:
https://anotepad.com/notes/mwapycep

Comment: Take the if-statement that I mentioned in my answer and add it just before `return(hash)` in your `vcl_recv` subroutine. This will bypass the cache for the shopping cart.

Comment: I do this:

`if(req.url ~ "^/module/ps_shoppingcart/ajax") {
        return(pass);
    }
  # Cache all others requests
  return (hash);
} `
but not work

Comment: Did you reload your VCL after editing the VCL file? This can either be done with the `varnishreload` command or by running `sudo systemctl reload varnish`.

Comment: Yes I do, `systemctl restart varnish`

Comment: I only have 1 thing left to test: send an HTTP request to `/module/ps_shoppingcart/ajax` explicitly via the browser or via curl. In the meanwhlie keep `varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl ~ '^/module/ps_shoppingcart/ajax'"` open en check for the values of the `VCL_call` and `VCL_return` tags. If we cannot get valuable information out of this test scenario, I don't have anymore ideas how to fix this issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241132/discussion-between-behnam-bahadori-and-thijs-feryn).

Comment: I found this details: postimg.cc/BP0kWhtp but I cant exclude shopping box ajax view from cache

Answer (score 0):

In your config file you should exclude the `req.method == "GET"` from the condition:

```
req.method == "GET" && (req.url ~'/ajax' || req.url ~ '^/ajax')
```

Comment: request like this:`BereqMethod POST  BereqURL /cart` and `ReqMethod      POST
-   ReqURL         /module/ps_shoppingcart/ajax`
but this regex not work
`if (req.method == "POST" && (req.url ~ "^/module" || req.url ~ "^/cart")) {
        return (pass);
    }`